# How do I resolve Repository not found errors in Teamcity?

Tags: github, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I've multiple projects configured exactly the same way using the same VCS root. All that changes for the projects is the project name, so to keep things DRY I share the root with the following fetch url:

```
git@github.com:<myorg>/%conf.GitProjectName%.git
```

For one single project this fails with:

```
List remote refs failed: cannot locate repository at git@github.com:<myorg>/<My project>.git: ERROR: Repository not found.
```

This is really weird and I can clone the git repo using `git@github.com:<myorg>/<My project>.git` without any problem. Any idea about how to debug this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was not due to teamcity, it was because of github's new way to give teams rights to a repository which wasn't there before I think. Didn't delete the question to help other that might have the problem.

Comment: What's the answer though?

Comment: @StealthRabbi the answer to my specific problem was that github had change their way in which they give teams rights to a repository as I wrote above. So you have to give the team access right to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I've failed to add two or more github reps to teamcity using the same private key. I've generated another private/public pair, added public key to github for new repo, then added private key into teamcity. This worked for me. Hope it helps.